# LINQ to XML: Ignoring of the case of attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, casing

I use LINQ to XML for working with PackageContents.xml file, created by Autodesk company. Company has defined the structure of this XML file [here](http://exchange.autodesk.com/autocad/enu/online-help/ACD/2012/ENU/pages/WS1a9193826455f5ff-4fe3487312ce8a8dba5-7feb.htm), but without XSD schema.

I have a problem: This company breaks his the rules... Often the case of elements and attributes is invalid. For example, instead of the "URL" attribute the "Url" attribute can be defined (different casing).

But [case is important for XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256152.aspx) (or, [in English](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256152.aspx)):

> Like element names, attribute names are case-sensitive and must start
>   with a letter or underscore.

The "URL" is not equals "Url" - such attribute will not found.

Can I solve this problem through LINQ to XML (or other), or I can't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it's correct that `myXelement.Attribute("URL")` would require the correct case, there's nothing stopping you doing

```
var attribute = x.Attributes()
                 .SingleOrDefault(xa => 
                     string.Equals(xa.Name.LocalName, 
                                   "Url", 
                                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Wrap this up in a suitable extension or static helper method and your consuming code shouldn't be too bad.